# Why does questions->unanswered not redirect to unanswered?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, unanswered-questions

Shouldn't https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered redirect to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered instead? (Same for all SE sites of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they shouldn't because they are two different views.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered points to questions that have zero answers.

where as

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered points to questions that do not have *accepted* answers.

EDIT:

The `Unanswered` tab is for questions that have no answers at all:

[image]

The `Questions` > `Unanswered` sub tab includes questions that have no answers but it also contains that questions that have answers but have no accepted answer.

[image]

Comment: I thought the definition of unanswered on SE was "no _upvoted_ answers", but anyway what you write seems to be wrong, there are plenty of questions on SO's unanswered tab with having-not-upvoted-answers-questions. But now that you mention it, questions?sort=unanswered seems to show only questions without answers, so maybe it's the other way around?

Comment: oh, sorry I missed that sub-tab, I always use "my tags"... but isn't questions->unanswered a duplicate of unanswered->newest or wouldn't it be less confusing to add that view to the unanswered tab anyhow?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: No because `Unanswered`>`Newest` are questions that have no *upvoted* answers.

Comment: so questions->unanswered contains questions with upvoted but not accepted answers as well?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Yes that is correct :)

Comment: @Tobias, a bit late, but I think you're right: [OK, Now Define “Answered”](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/)