# Another name for Question->Unanswered?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, homepage

I do not like that there are two "Unanswered" pages, but with the help of the question "[Why does questions->unanswered not redirect to unanswered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96116/why-does-questions-unanswered-not-redirect-to-unanswered)" I know that it makes sense.

But why they have not different names? I think it would be more beginner friendly or maybe search engine friendly if they have different names.

Unfortunately I must confess that I don't know possible alternatives. Maybe someone of you? Or is this question senseless? If so, why?

Comment: "Not answered enough"?

Answer (score 1):

A valid point.  Perhaps one of these, or some variation:

- Unsolved
- Unresolved
- Unsettled
- Open
- "Needs answer"

Comment: +1 I think "Unsolved" fits very well. The "Unanswered" page contains "questions with no upvoted answers" so they are "unsolved" or maybe "needs answer".